# Babylon JS - Using Camera from Blendr scene

Tags: babylonjs

I created a scene in Blendr 2.8 with a room, chair, a light, a camera.
I exported this to a .babylon file using the Blendr2Babylon 6.2.0 exporter, but upon import into babylon, it doesn't automatically use the camera created in blendr.

I've tried a variety of ways to import the babylon file, using

```
SceneLoader.Load
SceneLoader.ImportMesh
SceneLoader.Append
```

I think i'm missing the code that explicitly tells the scene to use the camera from the scene import from Blendr.

Does anyone have any code examples? I've been looking at babylon documentation but can't find any clear answers there

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

If you exported the camera as well, it should exist in the scene.cameras array.

I would first check if scene.activeCamera is set after loading / appending the scene. if it does exist, you just need to attach the camera to the canvas so that the user input will work:

```
// can also be SceneLoader.Append using an existing scene, here I used .Load
SceneLoader.Load("", "yourExportedScene.babylon", engine, function (scene) {
    if(!scene.activeCamera) {
        // assuming only one camera was exported. otherwise select using name/id
        scene.activeCamera = scene.cameras[0];
    }

    // attach the camera to receive user input
    scene.activeCamera.attachControl(htmlCanvasElement, false);
});
```